# What modules do you think would make ideal Perl 5 defaults?

Tags: perl, module

I'm looking to fork [Modern::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Modern-Perl/), it's over a year old now, and far dated. I've created [nextgen.pm](http://github.com/EvanCarroll/nextgen/blob/master/lib/nextgen.pm) (now on [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~ecarroll/nextgen/)) to take it place.

So far, I've added in:

- [`autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/autodie/lib/autodie.pm),
- and [`indirect`](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/indirect/lib/indirect.pm)

I assert `5.10.1`, so no one trying to write modern Perl gets caught up in the mess that is `5.10.0`'s smart match. I've also added conditional support for

- [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose/lib/Moose.pm),
- [`oose.pm`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose/lib/oose.pm),
- and [`namespace::clean`](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/namespace-clean/lib/namespace/clean.pm)

What else can you think of that might be valuable in a replacement for `Modern::Perl`? One thing that I've considered doing is trying to assert that a module was not included by the calling package (such as `Class::Accessor`). Any other ideas?

Comment: shouldn't this be a community wiki?

Comment: nextgen is a lousy name.  What do you do next year?  How about Modern::Perl::2011?

Comment: After nextgen comes ds9.pm, obviously.

Comment: Why not update the Modern::Perl package? Also: Aren't lowercase module names kind of "reserved"?

Comment: They're reserved for exactly this reason, I turn on strict and indirect which can both throw fatal exceptions, as well as interface with B. This fundamentally changes the behavior of perl.

Answer (score 9):

[Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try%3a%3aTiny)

EDIT: And definitely [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSlurp)

Answer (score 6):

You seem to import Moose unconditionally if you're not being imported into `main`. That's just wrong. Not every package is a class.

Comment: How would you suggest detecting if the package is a class?

Comment: Not at all. That's something only the caller knows. Instead you could provide keywords to allow the caller to declare what he wants, similar to how MX::Declare provides a class keyword.

Comment: I've added the `:procedural` token, which lets allows you to opt-into the non-OO paradigm. Short of that I'm totally comfortable with the assumption that modern perl users will be more inclined to program such that each package is a class. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Now what about packages that are roles? Also, there's paradigms other than OO that aren't just procedural. The name seems suboptimal.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: FWIW I like :procedural.  Much better than something like :nomoose.

Answer (score 4):

[Method::Signatures::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Method%3a%3aSignatures%3a%3aSimple), or some more advanced method and function signature mechanism.

Comment: My firm belief is that this should be a core feature instead. You know. After somebody implements the ro binds. :)

Comment: I dunno. "perl 5 defaults" could certainly also be interpreted as "core features" :-)

Answer (score 3):

Anything that's in [perl5i](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl5i/).

Comment: While perl5i is pretty cool, it goes way too far in the opinion of many experienced perl hackers. Only because something cool **can** be done really doesn't mean it **should** be done.

Comment: @rafl Do you have specifics for us?

Answer (score 3):

[`Moose::Autobox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aAutobox), or at least [`autobox::Core`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autobox%3a%3aCore).

Answer (score 1):

[Mouse](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mouse), [Any::Moose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Any-Moose), [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent), [Object::Event](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Object-Event), [Plack](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack), [DBIx::DataModel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-DataModel), [DBIx::Connector](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Connector)